# firewalld multiple public ips to multiple private ips routing

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, nat, firewalld

I'm trying to use CentOS 7 server as a firewall/nat for some sensitive servers on the LAN. The CentOS server has multiple public IPs (one per box on the LAN) and I'm trying to associate each external IP with a private IP in a way that will allow me to filter the sources/ports for the sensitive machines. The box itself has two NICs cards that are bonded as 'team0', so that adds some complexity to all this.

I have read *many* posts online over the past few days, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

So far I have these two rules in the Direct Configuration in firewalld:

```
ipv4 nat PREROUTING 0 -i team0 -d <public ip> -j DNAT --to-destination 10.100.37.10/32
ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -d 10.100.37.10/32 -j ACCEPT
```

I also added this 'rich' rule to the trusted zone:

```
ipv4 accept port 3389/tcp <my ip> <public ip>
```

This doesn't work, and I can't seem to get it to work no matter what I try.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/RyNb8Ewf) is the full iptables -L

[Here](http://pastebin.com/j1DPpLrQ) is the iptables -L -t nat

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this it driving me insane...
Let me know if i need to provide any information to make this easier to work with.

Comment: I would question why you would want this.  If you just want to filter ports, either a firewall, or firewall rules on each host would do it.  If you don't want the servers accessible on the public ip, except as a forward to the private ip, then a firewall with nat on it would do it.  What you have seems a little complex for the result you seem to want.

Comment: my general approach to firewalld is to avoid it at all costs... Would you consider rewriting the required functionality in a clean bare iptables setup and then convert to firewalld once its working?